# Optimizing my update sequence

Tags: mysql, optimization, update

Whenever a user updates his profile, we conduct a set of queries like so:

```
DELETE FROM `user_likes` WHERE `ID` = $id
INSERT INTO `user_likes` VALUES (DEFAULT, $id, $interest_id, $interest_name)
```

Is there a way to do this all in one step? There has to be a way, because the interest IDs are all different for each user. Keep in mind that the data never actually has to be deleted - it's a set that is always growing.

Comment: `UPDATE` .......

Comment: If you don't want to delete anything, why do you run a `DELETE` statement?

Comment: I'm assuming OP's likes are an accumulating table (lack of deletion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a unique pair index for your `user_id` and `interest_id` in the `user_likes` table.

Then use:

```
INSERT IGNORE VALUES (DEFAULT, $id, $interest_id, $interest_name), ...
```

to insert the values, having the database check for previous existence of the pair.

Comment: This is not the same as deleting and inserting a new row.

Comment: @ypercube, please read my edit to the question. This answer does do what I want (no need for deletion), I wouldn't have accepted it otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

If you just updating the interest id and name, use `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE user_likes SET
`interest_id` = $interest_id,
`interest_name` = '$interest_name'
WHERE `ID` = $id;
```

If you want to mechanically do a `DELETE` followed by an `UPDATE`, use `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE INTO `user_likes` VALUES (DEFAULT, $id, $interest_id, $interest_name);
```

Please test these out on a Dev DB Server to make sure this is what you want

Comment: +1, I hadn't known `REPLACE` was valid with a `DEFAULT` value